# Inserting in Max heap with Key_Class as in parameter

Tags: java, data-structures, heap

I have to make my insert function follow the logic for a Max heap with a Key_Class as in parameter. So I actually have 2 questions.

1. What is this Key_Class and how do I access the values inside it for comparison?
2. How could I write my insert function?

   ```
   public class MinPQ<Key_Class> {
   private Key_Class[] pq;                    // store keys at index 1..n
   private int count;                         // number of keys currently stored.
   private boolean orderOK;                   // flag to keep internal track of when the heap is ordered / not ordered
   /**
    * Initialize a new queue with the given capacity.
    * @param  initCapacity initial capacity of the internal array
    */
   public MinPQ(int initCapacity) {
       pq = (Key_Class[]) new Object[initCapacity + 1];
       count = 0;
   }

   /**
    * Initialize a new queue with default size 100.
    */

   public MinPQ() {
       this(100);
   }

   /**
    * Initialize a priority queue based on an ArrayList of keys.
    * @param  keys ArrayList of keys.
    */
   public MinPQ(ArrayList<Key_Class> keys) {
       count = keys.size();
       pq = (Key_Class[]) new Object[count + 1];
       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           pq[i+1] = keys.get(i);
       }
       fixHeap();
       assert isMinHeap();
   }

   /**
    * Get the size of the queue. 
    */
   public int size() {
       return count;
   }

   /**
    * Check is the queue is empty.
    * @return true if the queue is empty, false otherwise.
    */
   public boolean isEmpty() {
       return count == 0;
   }

   /**
    * Get the smallest key in the queue.
    * @return the smallest key in queue.
    * @throws MinPQError if there is no key in the queue.
    */
   public Key_Class findMin() {
   if (isEmpty()) {
       throw new MinPQError("Priority queue empty");
   }
   return pq[1];
   }

   /**
    * Add a new key to the queue.
    * @param  x the key to be added to the queue.
    */
   ```

   **this is the function I'm supposed to write**

   ```
   public void insert(Key_Class x) {
       pq[++count] = x;
       //if(pq[count] > pq[count-1])       
       throw new MinPQError("Insert needs to be implemented!");
   }
   ```

**The rest is supportive functions I'm supposed to make use of **

```
    /**
     * Remove and return the smallest key in the queue.
     * @return the smallest key in the queue.
     * @throws MinPQError if the queue is empty. 
     */
    public Key_Class delMin() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new MinPQError("Priority queue underflow");
        }
        if (!orderOK) {
            fixHeap();
        }
        Key_Class min = pq[1];
        swap_indexes(1, count--);
        sink(1);
        pq[count+1] = null;     // remove the old key
        if ((count > 0) && (count == (pq.length - 1) / 4)) { // shrink the array as needed to save memory
            resize(pq.length / 2);
        }
        assert isMinHeap();
        return min;
    }

    /**
     * Insert the key x on the first available position, without preserving the heap property.
     * Doubles are permitted.
     */
    public void toss(Key_Class x) {
        orderOK = false;
        // Double the size of the queue as needed
        if (count == pq.length - 1) {
            resize(2 * pq.length);
        }
        // Places the item in the first available position
        pq[++count] = x;        
    }

    //***************************************************************************
    //*                           Help Functions                                *
    //***************************************************************************
    // Help function to assist with doubling the size of the internal array.
    private void resize(int capacity) {
        assert capacity > count;
        Key_Class[] temp = (Key_Class[]) new Object[capacity];
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            temp[i] = pq[i];
        }
        pq = temp;
    }

    //***************************************************************************
    //*          Help functions to aid in restoring the heap property           *
    //***************************************************************************

    private void swim(int k) {
    while (k > 1 && greater(k/2, k)) {
        swap_indexes(k, k/2);
        k = k/2;
    }
    }

    private void sink(int k) {
        while (2*k <= count) {
            int j = 2*k;
            if (j < count && greater(j, j+1)) {
            j++;
            }
            if (!greater(k, j)) {
            break;
            }
            swap_indexes(k, j);
            k = j;
        }
    }

    private void fixHeap() {
        for (int k = count/2; k >= 1; k--) {// Återställer heap-egenskapen
            sink(k);
        }
        orderOK = true;
    }
    //***************************************************************************
    //*                 Help functions for comparisons and moves                *
    //***************************************************************************

    private boolean greater(int i, int j) {
        return ((Comparable<Key_Class>) pq[i]).compareTo(pq[j]) > 0;
    }

    private void swap_indexes(int i, int j) {
        Key_Class swap = pq[i];
        pq[i] = pq[j];
        pq[j] = swap;
    }

    // Is pq[1..N] a min heap?
    private boolean isMinHeap() {
        return isMinHeap(1);
    }

    // Is the subtree of pq[1..n] rooted at k a min heap?
    private boolean isMinHeap(int k) {
        if (k > count) {
            return true;
        }
        int left = 2*k;
        int right = 2*k + 1;
        if (left  <= count && greater(k, left))  {
            return false;
        }
        if (right <= count && greater(k, right)) {
            return false;
        }
        return isMinHeap(left) && isMinHeap(right);
    }

}
```

Comment: To add to a binary heap, you put the new item in the first unused position (i.e. `pq[count+1]`, increase the count, and then call `swim` to move it up to its proper position.

Comment: By the way, I don't know if the code is yours or if somebody else provided it to you, but creating a binary heap where the root is at index 1 is silly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49806133/56778 and http://blog.mischel.com/2016/09/19/but-thats-the-way-weve-always-done-it/. Feel free to pass that on to the originator of the code, if it's not you.

Comment: @JimMischel Thank you very much for your input. It was perhaps too simple to see, I will forward this to the original author of the code.