# How do I access minimum element using array-based binary heap?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to implement an array-based, fixed-size minimum binary heap ADT. As I was testing my program, all the functions I wrote seem to work fine except for finding the minimum element which is only supposed to return the integer value stored at the root node. The root node in this implementation is placed at index 1.
The error I keep getting is the read-access violation.
The following is the Binary Heap class definition and the implementation of the functions:

```cpp
class BinaryHeap {

public:
    BinaryHeap(int); // constructor that takes the capacity of the structure
    ~BinaryHeap(); // destructor
    void insert(int); // inserts a new element to the heap
    void deleteMin(); // removes the minimum element from the heap
    int getMin(); // returns the minimum element int the heap, returns -1 if the heap is empty

private:
    int *heap; // array to store the elements of the heap
    int size; // keeps the number of elements in the heap
    int capacity; // keeps the total capacity of the heap
    void percolateDown(int);
    void percolateUp(int);
    void swap(int, int);
};


BinaryHeap::BinaryHeap(int capacity) {
    this->capacity = capacity;

    heap = new int[capacity+1];
    size = 0;
}

BinaryHeap::~BinaryHeap() {
    delete [] heap;
}

void BinaryHeap::insert(int element) {

    if (size < capacity) {
        size++;
        heap[size] = element;
        percolateUp(size);
    }
    else return;
}

void BinaryHeap::deleteMin() {

    if (size < 1) 
        return;
    else {
        heap[1] = heap[size];
        size--;
        percolateDown(1);
    }
}

int BinaryHeap::getMin() {
    if (size < 1)
        return -1;
    else return heap[1];
}

void BinaryHeap::percolateDown(int hole) {


    int leftChildIndex, rightChildIndex, minIndex;
    leftChildIndex = hole * 2;
    rightChildIndex = hole * 2 + 1;
    if (rightChildIndex >= size) {
        if (leftChildIndex >= size) return;
        else minIndex = leftChildIndex;
    }
    else {
        if (heap[leftChildIndex] <= heap[rightChildIndex])
            minIndex = leftChildIndex;
        else
            minIndex = rightChildIndex;
    }

    if (heap[hole] > heap[minIndex]) {
        swap(hole, minIndex);
        percolateDown(minIndex);
    }
}
void BinaryHeap::percolateUp(int index) {
    int parentIndex(1);
    if (index != 1) {
        parentIndex = index / 2;
    }
    if (heap[parentIndex] > heap[index]) {
        swap(parentIndex, index);
        percolateUp(parentIndex);
    }

}

void BinaryHeap::swap(int i, int j) {
    int t = heap[i];
    heap[i] = heap[j];
    heap[j] = t;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element

Comment: *I am trying to implement an array-based, fixed size minimum binary heap ADT* -- Is there a reason why you're not using the ready-made [heap functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap)?

Comment: It is a course assignment, I am supposed to implement it.

Comment: If that's the case, then what you're showing us doesn't really help unless we see all the code.  Also, arrays are 0-based, not 1 based.  Why are you assuming that the array has at least 2 elements?

Comment: The constructor creates an array of a user specified size+1 and places the first element at index 1.

Comment: Why not at index zero?

Comment: It was implemented by my professor that way, it is because it makes it easier to access children/parent indexes using leftchild=index*2, rightchild=index*2+1 and parent=index/2.

Comment: *it is because it makes it easier to access children/parent indexes using leftchild=index*2, rightchild=index*2+1 and parent=index/2.* - -So your professor is trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.  C++ starts arrays at 0, not 1.  By faking a 1-based array, you are at risk of either falling of the right edge, causing a memory access error, or erroneously accessing element 0, resulting in wrong calculations.  Believe me, I've seen this hundreds of times before, where the coder is trying this and then wind up with these issues.

Comment: I assume this is a data structures course, because if its a C or C++ course, I'd say run from that prof as fast as your legs can carry you. Fwiw, the math for a binary heap in an array sequence is *easier*, not harder, when it is zero-based. Just saying.

Comment: @Maram -- Please post a [mcve].  No one can help with the code you posted, since anyone could take your code, add some dummy functions, and cause all sorts of havoc with the program.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie -- Thank you so much for all your feedback, I edited the code to include the complete implementation. I understand now why it is wrong to start the array at index 1. But, since the assignment specifically requires me to use this way of implementation, and the testing source file also depends on this implementation, unfortunately I cannot change it.

Comment: @Maram -- Can you post the sample `main` with the data?

Comment: If you single-step your program in the debugger, you'll find your read access violation pretty quickly. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn. Where are you getting the error? You should be able to use `cout` to identify the specific line in your `main` that causes the error. From there, you can track the calls.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49806133/56778. I think your instructor should read this. Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22900767/56778

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your `percolateDown` function.

```
void BinaryHeap::percolateDown(int hole) {
    int leftChildIndex, rightChildIndex, minIndex;
    leftChildIndex = hole * 2;
    rightChildIndex = hole * 2 + 1;

    if (rightChildIndex >= size) {
        if (leftChildIndex >= size) return;
        else minIndex = leftChildIndex;
    }
    else {
        if (heap[leftChildIndex] <= heap[rightChildIndex])
            minIndex = leftChildIndex;
        else
            minIndex = rightChildIndex;
    }

    if (heap[hole] > heap[minIndex]) {
        swap(heap[hole], heap[minIndex]);
        percolateDown(minIndex);
    }
}
```

Let's assume you have 4 items in your heap. Visually, it looks like this:

```
         1
       /   \
      3     2
     /
    4
```

The array, since you start your heap at 1, would contain `[0,1,3,2,4]`, and `size` is `4`. You call `deleteMin`, which moves the last item to the front, giving you `[0,4,3,2,4]`, with `size = 3`. Then it calls `percolateDown(1)`.

`percolateDown` computes `leftChildIndex = 2` and `rightChildIndex = 3`. Then you hit this:

```
`if (rightChildIndex >= size)`
```

But `rightChildIndex` is equal to `3`, which is the same as `size`. So the code  will never enter the conditional to compare the right child with the left child. Instead, it will compare the left child with the parent, find that it's less, and swap the nodes. You will end up with this invalid heap:

```
         3
       /   \
      4     2
```

It's interesting to note that the `>=` check on the indexes is a common idiom when dealing with 0-based arrays. But the code you're working with treats the array as though it's 1-based. And with 1-based arrays the standard idiom is `>`. This is one of the reasons I strongly recommend putting the root node of a binary heap at 0 when you're working with a language that has 0-based arrays.

A cleaner (and correct) way to do this would be:

```
    int leftChildIndex, rightChildIndex, minIndex;
    leftChildIndex = hole * 2;
    rightChildIndex = hole * 2 + 1;

    if (leftChildIndex > size) {
        // if the left child index is outside the heap,
        // then the right child index will be, too.
        return;
    }

    // assume left is smallest
    minIndex = leftChildIndex;

    // and only check the right if it exists
    if (rightChildIndex <= size) {
        if (heap[rightChildIndex] < heap[leftChildIndex]) {
            minIndex = rightChildIndex;
        }
    }
```